# Program received signal SIGSEGV, segmentation fault, Linked list program

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node{
    int value;
    struct node* next;
}Node;

Node* createNode(int data);
Node* insertFront(Node* first, Node* newNode);
void printList(Node* first); 
void deleteList(Node* first);

int main(int argc, const char **argv)
{
    int numItems, ch;
    FILE *fp;

    fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    while ((ch = getc(fp)) != EOF)
    {
        if (ch = '\n') numItems++;
    }
    fclose(fp);

    Node *first = NULL;
    Node *newNode;
    Node *Next;

    int i;

    for(i = 1; i <= numItems; i++)
    {
        newNode = createNode(i);
        first = insertFront(first, newNode);
    }

    printList(first);
    deleteList(first);

    return 1;
}

Node* createNode(int data)
{
    Node *newNode;

    newNode = malloc(sizeof(Node));

    newNode -> value = data;

    newNode -> next = NULL;

    return newNode;
}

Node* insertFront(Node* first, Node* newNode)
{
    if (newNode == NULL) {
        /* handle oom */
    }

    newNode->next=NULL;

    if (first == NULL) {
        first = newNode;
    }

    else {
        Node *temp=first;

        while(temp->next!=NULL)
        {
            temp = temp->next;
        }

        temp->next=newNode;

        first = newNode;
    }

    return first;
}

void printList(Node* first)
{
    Node *temp;
    temp=first;

    printf("elements in linked list are\n");
    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
        printf("%d\n",temp->value);
        temp=temp->next;
    }
}

void deleteList(Node* first)
{
    Node  *temp;
    temp=first;
    first=first->next;
    temp->next=NULL;
    free(temp);
}
```

Tried running with gdb and this is what I got, first real experience trying to make a linked list.

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
_IO_getc (fp=0x0) at getc.c:40
40        _IO_acquire_lock (fp);

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here? Thanks for any tips in advance.

Comment: `numItems` is uninitialised.

Comment: Just looks like its failing to open the file. fopen() returns NULL, you pass that to getc(), and that crashes. Always check the return value of fopen() and other library functions that can easily fail!

Comment: Before asking a question, read [SSCCE](http://sscce.org). You could probably solve this by trimming the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not initialize numItems to zero. As unitialized it can be any number, including e.g. negative ones. Because of this your list is not created, hence pointer *first* points to NULL. Then the code segfaults in the function *deleteList*, when it tries to free memory at location NULL.

Comment: It is okay to do free(NULL), but it is undefined behavior to read uninitialized data.